# Help with a SQL query with a couple of foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables structure:

Shipment (has IDDestination as foreign key) -> Destination (has IDCity as foreign key) -> City (has IDCountry as foreign key).

I want to give my stored procedure a Country ID and have it return all of the shipments. How would I do this with pure SQL syntax? I could do this trivially with an ORM, but I'm forcing myself to learn this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INNER JOINs to link all your tables together.

```
CREATE GetShipments

@CountryID int

AS

SELECT *
FROM Shipments
INNER JOIN Destination ON Shipment.IDDestination = Destination.ID
INNER JOIN Cities ON Destination.IDCity = Cities.ID
WHERE Cities.IDCountry = @CountryID
```

Comment: Thanks!  Also, Tahbaza is right, you would want to SELECT Shipments.*, otherwise you'll get all the Destination and City information as well, which you may or may not need.

Comment: I must admit, I am jealous of your username ever time I see it

Comment: @OMG Ponies - And to think, I was about to register with my real name (sadly, not Bobby) when I had the stroke of insight.  While we're at it, I'm jealous of your reputation and your lightning-quick response time.

Comment: Both rep & response are due to putting time into SO.  It's been very educational for me

Answer (score 2):

For a [visual demonstration of various JOINs, see this link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Assuming @idcountry is an integer data type, use:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE get_shipments_for_countryid 
   @idcountry INT
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT DISTINCT 
          s.*
     FROM SHIPMENT s
     JOIN DESTINATION d ON d.id = s.iddestination
     JOIN CITY c ON c.id = d.idcity 
    WHERE c.idcountry = @idcountry
END
GO
```

Change the parameter data type, if not an INT, to whatever is appropriate.

The `DISTINCT` is necessary if any of the tables are many-to-many, or one-to-many...

Comment: SELECT sys.* ?  Somebody's been working with system tables a lot lately :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Stupid SSMS 2008 intellisense, did it even though I selected my `example` database...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM City c INNER JOIN (
  Shipment s INNER JOIN Destination d ON s.IDDestination = d.ID)
  ON c.ID = d.IDCity
WHERE c.IDCountry = @IDCountry
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but won't this select a list of Cities?

Comment: @Sergio: What?! Shipment s means "use s as an alias for the SHIPMENT table" why would a list of cities be returned???  As a matter of fact the other responses WITHOUT a prefix for the * will return a lot more fields that you probably aren't interested in...

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe...

```
select * from Shipment as s
inner join Destination as d on s.IDDestination = d.IDDestination
inner join City as c on d.IDCountry = c.IDCountry
where c.IDCountry = @CountryID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM Shipment S
JOIN Destination D on S.IDDestination  = D.ID
JOIN City C on D.IDCity = C.ID
WHERE IDCountry = @IDCountry
```